# Calling jQuery function per id or better grouping in to one call

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I was wondering if it would be an performance improvement if i group some `id`'s in one call for a jQuery function, or call it line by line (`id` after `id`).

For the moment it is like this:

```
$('#culetType').combobox();
$('#girdle').combobox();
$('#polishLinesIntensity').combobox();
$('#burnmarksIntensity').combobox();
$('#scratchesIntensity').combobox();
$('#damagesIntensity').combobox();
```

So would it be an performance improvement if i dit this:

```
$('#culetType, #girdle, #polishLinesIntensity, #burnmarksIntensity, #scratchesIntensity, #damagesIntensity').combobox();
```

Besides the fact that it not pleasant to read.

I know i could give all those `id`'s a `class`, and that would leave me with only one call.

So would it be an performance boost or not?

Comment: in fact: selecting by class is much slower than using id selectors! if you just use it once, it might be ok.

Comment: using id's will always be faster than class

Comment: Sites like [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/) allow you to create benchmarks to reliably measure how switching to class selectors will impact the performance of your specific code, depending on the browser.

Comment: A good general rule is to optimise if you run into performance issues right? I think I'd go for classes here for the readability / maintainability and worry about performance only if it caused an issue.

Comment: You can have a look at [this small test case](http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-selector-grouped) I created in jspref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer browsers using a single selector will give a slight performance boost, because jQuery uses the built in method to run the selector. Creating a single jQuery object and do the operation on all elements in it is slightly faster than creating a bunch of jQuery objects.

In older browsers it will be slightly faster to parse the selector containing a single id, but it will be slightly slower to create multiple jQuery objects, so the methods would perform about the same.

Comment: based on the comment from Frédéric & Arun, i tried using jsperf: result is the same as you where saying. http://jsperf.com/single-vs-multiple-call

Answer (score 1):

As I know writing `$()` makes call to DOM every time. So even in you call some element better to do:

```
el = $('#myEl');
el.firstAction();
el.secondAction();
```

instead of

```
$('#myEl').firstAction();
$('#myEl').secondAction();
```

So I think make one call with `$('...,...,...')` will work faster but it will be small boost.

But you need to remember that in case of one call you cant do  something like:

```
$('#culetType').combobox();
$('#girdle').combobox({property: false});
$('#polishLinesIntensity').combobox();
```